# DataAnnotation and Code First to Create Foreign Key to ApplicationUser using Identity 2.2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations, entity-framework-migrations

## Intro

I'm trying to build a code first table which will have a 3rd table relating it to the ApplicationUser. I've been searching SO and Google, as I always do, to find a solution to my problem as I'm sure I'm not the first to run into this, but all the solutions I've tried are not working. Maybe it's because of the version of ASP.NET Identity (v 2.2.1) I'm using requires a different solution than what I'm finding or There are concepts I'm not familiar with yet.

Essentially, what I'm trying to build is exactly what the [IdentityUserRole](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUserRole.cs) class is with different meaning. I want to build it using DataAnnotations and not [the method they used](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs). While I do appreciate other solutions and ways of doing the same thing, and I'm working on a real project, I do like to learn and at the very least want to learn how to do it with DataAnnotation.

With that said, here's the good stuff:

## Classes

`Sections` class, which would be relative to the [IdentityRole](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityRole.cs) class

```
public class Sections {
    [Key]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public virtual String Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("SectionsNameIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    [Display(Name = "Section Name")]
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `UserSections` class, which would be relative to the [IdentityUserRole](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUserRole.cs) class

### Version 1

```
public class UserSections {
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Index]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual String UserId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [Index]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public virtual String SectionId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Sections Section { get; set; }
}
```

### Version 2

```
public class UserSections {
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Index]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public virtual String UserId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [Index]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public virtual String SectionId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("SectionId")]
    public virtual Sections Section { get; set; }
}
```

## Problem

Problem is for either version I get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> {MyProjectName}.DataContexts.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> {MyProjectName}.DataContexts.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

## Question(s)

How can I use DataAnnotations to get this to work like the `IdentityUserRoles` **without, if possible,** creating a third class to extend the `ApplicationUser` class?

## Update #1

Based on answers given, here is some more info. I did create a secondary context to keep it away from the identity context. When I tried using the same context used with identity portion it worked. However, is there a way to do this using a **different** context?

Comment: The problem is in the definition of IdentityUserLogin and IdentityUserRole which you're not showing. I don't know what the errors have to do with the code you're showing. Please, edit your question and so the code affected by the problem. If you tell that your ankle aches, and you show your wrist, you can't be helped.

Comment: Do you use `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` as `DbContext`?

Comment: @JotaBe I linked you to the source code for IdentityUserRoles which you can go to it by clicking on it. You can then review the source code for IdentityUserLogins.

Comment: If you are going to link to ApplicationUser, which lives in the IdentityContext, then you need to either have your application context inherit from IdentityDbContext as Stephen suggests, or you need to add a cloned ApplicationUser class to your context.

Comment: @StephenReindl, for identity objects yes. But for these classes no, I created another context to keep migrations separated between identity and my other application specific classes. Should I be using the same context? I'll try it out.

Comment: @SteveGreene, thanks. I will try that now.

Comment: @StephenReindl, yes it worked when I switched them to the other context. I learned the concept of using two contexts to separate identity migrations and the migrations concerning the rest of the app. i guess it didn't click that if I was to use a class within identity, I would have to use the same context. If you post it as an answer I can accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Stephen Reindl and Steve Greene, the solution to my problem was to use the same context that I was using for the `ApplicationUser`.